# PHP PDO There is no active transaction

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, sqltransaction

I tried to run a query with PDO class and got this error message: `"There is no active transaction"` when trying to commit.

Here's my code:

```
  public function runExQuery($sql) {
        $preparedQuery = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $this->connect()->beginTransaction();
        $preparedQuery->execute();
        $this->connect()->commit();
}



private function connect() {
        return new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->database . '', $this->username, $this->password);
    }
```

What is the cause of this error? I explored previous posts of this type of question, but did not find any solutions.

Comment: Does `$this->connect()` create a NEW PDO object each time it is called? If so, you need to reuse the same object.

Comment: my connect method posted there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `::connect()` method is creating a new PDO each time you call it.

Since transactions do not survive outside of connections, the reconnecting wipes it out.

To correct this, store the PDO object as a class property:

```
class MyPdoClass
{
    private $pdo;
    // ... 

    public function connect()
    {
        if ($this->pdo instanceof PDO) {
            return;
        }
        $this->pdo = new PDO(// .... 
    }
```

and then reference it after calling connect:

```
//...
    public function runExQuery($query)
    {
        $this->connect();
        $this->pdo->prepare($query);
        // ... 
    }
```

Comment: After you posted the content of your connect method, I added some detail; see if that helps sort it out.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new PDO object every time you call `$this->connect()`, so if you have:

```
$stmt1 = $this->connect()->prepare(" ... ");
$stmt2 = $this->connect()->prepare(" ... ");
```

`$stmt1` and `$stmt2` will actually be completely different PDO objects, so if you start a transaction with one object, it will NOT apply to the other one. Instead you should save a PDO object and reference that instead of creating a new one every time.

Most of the time, I find it easier just to pass this to the class's constructor, however if you want to do minimal editing, you could just do:

```
class YourClass {
    private $dbh;
    private function connect() {
        if (!isset($this->dbh)) {
            $this->dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->database, $this->username, $this->password);
        }
        return $this->dbh;
    }
}
```

However you might want to change the name `connect()` to something a bit more logical, like `getDbh()`.

If instead you wanted to put it in the object's constructor, you could do this:

```
class YourClass {
    private $dbh;
    public function __construct(PDO $dbh) {
        $this->dbh = $dbh;
    }
}

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $database, $username, $password);
$yourclass = new YourClass($dbh);
```

Then in any of the other class methods, you would just reference `$this->dbh`. Using your code as an example:

```
public function runExQuery($sql) {
    $preparedQuery = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    $this->dbh->beginTransaction();
    $preparedQuery->execute();
    $this->dbh->commit();
}
```

Personally, this is the way I would do it.